# Issue building project with JavaScript APIs

Tags: dart, dart2js, dart-js-interop

Whenever I serve my project with the `--release`  options or I build it, and run it on the webpage, I'm getting this errors  console, and some features won't work, using the `dartdevc` compiler all the functions works fine.

For example this happens when I click a button:

```
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: ((w.event.special[a.origType] || {}).handle || a.handler).apply is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at r.t.show (modal.js:117)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:515)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
trigger @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
trigger @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
t.show @ modal.js:117
(anonymous) @ modal.js:515
each @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
r._jQueryInterface @ modal.js:498
cr @ index.dart.js:316
J.h4 @ index.dart.js:6202
dart.nN @ index.dart.js:6096
$1 @ index.dart.js:4961
m6 @ index.dart.js:980
(anonymous) @ index.dart.js:989
```

These are my `js` APIs called from Dart:

```
@JS()
library js_helper;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@anonymous
@JS()
class SnackbarParams {
  external factory SnackbarParams({String text, String pos, String backgroundColor});

  external String get text;
  external String get pos;
  external String get backgroundColor;

}

@JS('Snackbar')
class Snackbar{
  external static void show(SnackbarParams obj);
}

@JS('\$')
external dynamic jQuery(query);

@JS()
@anonymous
class ModalElement {

  external dynamic modal(String call);
  external dynamic on(String event, Function callback);

}

@JS()
@anonymous
class jFormElement {
  external dynamic serialize();
}
```

And this should be the code that is creating this error:

`(jQuery('#loginModal') as ModalElement).modal('show');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the issue was in the `on` method, I needed to add `allowInterop` to the `Function`